# How to do this complex knot cable?

Tags: modeling, texturing

At work my boss has been really frustrated because we don't know how to do the My little diamond cable in 3D with good texture.. we always do something who look off.
I feel like putting a texture on a simple tube won't work.
Here is what we are trying to achieve :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaHd8.jpg)
[image]

I'm trying to understand how to do this in blender then export in keyshot.
I will also ask on the keyshot stack exchange because it is the industry standard but my love for blender will forever stay ;)

Here is a mega link with the object with are trying to work with : https://mega.nz/file/ov5wiaAD#buIksBpoAgYFA8w6cvAm_Oc72aZPkKmiBv5mfO5P5qk

we've been stuck on this subject for like a month now lol

Comment: Hello I can't open your .obj, but what are you struggling with, the shape? the material?

Comment: @moonboots the shape and the material -_-

Comment: @moonboots i'll try to send you a better file

Comment: @moonboots https://mega.nz/file/lroEiJYI#VoOjs_d0LCEiXW0VvSa6pevU3G3bIZf116RrVovomu0
This is a STL file, need to separate by loose parts

Comment: Have you tried with braided hair? You can make it editable and exported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it this way (it needs to be improved). Create a half circle:

[image]

Duplicate, rotate:

[image]

Rotate 45° on Y:

[image]

Duplicate, rotate 90° on Y:

[image]

Array, give it a *Skin* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Link-duplicate 2 times, it seems like these are 3 ropes intertwined:

[image]

Give it a material (probably needs a bit of hair):

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: Hi thanks you a lot, can you send me the file or just the curve, i want to learn how to do it, i struggle to visualize what you have done

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/yZMbz3vs

Comment: thanks you a lot